# Need to generate a paper trail of documents transferred

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, nas, file-management

I'm doing work for a small law firm that is storing several terabytes of documents on a network shared folder on one of the workstations in their office.  I'm setting them up with a dedicated fault-tolerant NAS. They want a paper trail of the transfer, or at the very least, a paper audit that confirms that every file that exists on their old server exists on the new server.  How can I do this?

A recursive listing of the contents of both directories and a simple `diff` would suffice, but I'm sure I'm not the only person to have this need. Worst comes to worst I can write a shell script to (there's gotta be a recursive option for `ls` right?) output the contents to a file and diff the files.

It'd be preferable if this were doable in Windows.  I'm not as familiar with Powershell/batch as I am with bash, but all the office machines are Windows and I'd like to be able to set it overnight and forget it.  Otherwise, I may have to leave my laptop overnight to let a bash script do its thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CMD`, if you use `xcopy` and log the output, this will give you an audit which can be printed, though you will probably want to format it with a word processor before you do so. The command would be:

```
xcopy /s /v SourceDir TargetDir >xcopy.log 2>&1
```

After it completes you can quickly check that there were no failures with:

```
xcopy /s /d /v SourceDir TargetDir >xcopyFailures.log 2>&1
```

The second log should be empty, but if not there should be very few entries.

If you want to use Linux, you can achieve similar results with `rsync -axv ...`. Note that if you want a quick check by repeating the command you will need to compare the file time-stamp resolution on the source and target directories, and if necessary use `--modify-window` on the second call.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up doing what I described in the second paragraph and it worked better than I expected. In powershell (bc I needed to learn fresh, might as well learn the newer one) on one of the office machines:

`cd` to the new server's root

`dir -Recurse | Out-File 'path\to\CONTENTS_NEWSERVER.txt'`

`cd` to the old server's root

`dir -Recurse | Out-File 'path\to\CONTENTS_OLDSERVER.txt'`

This created two files... a paper trail!

After that, I simply ran Compare-Object to confirm everything I needed to know (and saved that file too).

Still wondering: any good ways to tackle ignoring hidden files and thumbs dbs and such? Those are the only things that were different and made for one heck of a time double checking the diff file to make sure there were no real files listed in it.

I marked AFH's answer as correct out of appreciation, and because he explained it in CMD/batch terms which is nice to have.